When exactly can/should I use aliases in SQL?
I have the following code (which works correctly):
with t as 
        (select *,

         dense_rank() over (partition by departmentId order by salary desc) as r 
       from employee
  )


select d.name as Department, t.name as Employee, t.Salary

from (t left join department d on t.departmentid=d.id) 

where 
    t.r <=3
    

What I don't understand is, why do I get an error if I try to give an alias to the joined table:
with t as 
        (select *,

         dense_rank() over (partition by departmentId order by salary desc) as r 
       from employee
  )


select d.name as Department, t.name as Employee, t.Salary

from (t left join department d on t.departmentid=d.id) as x

where 
    x.r <=3
    

I get that an alias is not necessary, but I don't get why it gives an error.
I expected the code to work just fine with the alias

What is the error?

(t left join department d on t.departmentid=d.id) is not a table reference, it is two table references. t and left join department d on t.departmentid=d.id. It makes no sense to give them collectively an alias, t.r and d.name are unambiguous.
The parens allowed but unnecessary and imply a grouping which does not exist. It's simpler to get rid of them.
with t as (
  select 
    *,
    dense_rank() over (
      partition by departmentId 
      order by salary desc
    ) as r 
  from employee
)
select 
  d.name as Department, 
  t.name as Employee, 
  t.Salary
from t
left join department d on t.departmentId=d.id
where t.r <=3

See 15.2.13.2 JOIN Clause
